# Daily Recurring Appointments in Calender getting stored as Weekly Recurring Appointments in Outlook 2013

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in

Here is my code:

```
Outlook.AppointmentItem oMeet;

Meeting Meet;

Hashtable htrecc = GetReccuranceTable(strRec);

  if (Meet.recctype.Substring(0, 3) == "day")

  {

     oMeet.GetRecurrencePattern().RecurrenceType = OlRecurrenceType.olRecursDaily;

     oMeet.GetRecurrencePattern().Interval = Convert.ToInt32(htrecc["Interval"]);

     if (string.Equals("no", htrecc["Occurence"]))

         oMeet.GetRecurrencePattern().NoEndDate = true;

     else

          if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(htrecc["Occurence"])))

              oMeet.GetRecurrencePattern().Occurrences = Convert.ToInt32(htrecc["Occurence"]);

          else

              oMeet.GetRecurrencePattern().PatternEndDate = Meet.EndTime;

    }
```

Please Suggest if I am going wrong anywhere because whenever I am trying to insert a Daily Appointment into the calendar it gets converted into a Weekly Appointment on the Calendar

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend starting from breaking the chain of property and method calls and declaring them on separate lines of code. Each time you call the GetRecurrencePattern method in the code you get a new instance.

When you work with recurring appointment items, you should release any prior references, obtain new references to the recurring appointment item before you access or modify the item, and release these references as soon as you are finished and have saved the changes. This practice applies to the recurring AppointmentItem object, and any Exception or RecurrencePattern object. To release a reference in Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) or Visual Basic, set that existing object to Nothing. In C#, explicitly release the memory for that object. Use [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject.aspx) to release an Outlook object when you have finished using it. Then set a variable to Nothing in Visual Basic (null in C#) to release the reference to the object. Read more about that in the [Systematically Releasing Objects article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb623945(v=office.12).aspx).

Note that even after you release your reference and attempt to obtain a new reference, if there is still an active reference, held by another add-in or Outlook, to one of the above objects, your new reference will still point to an out-of-date copy of the object. Therefore, it is important that you release your references as soon as you are finished with the recurring appointment.